# How do I return a number from a promise?

Tags: javascript, api, promise, return-value

I am trying to return an number (expensePerProduct), which I will use to "PUT" the data in to an object, but this function returns a promise object and not just a number :( What do I do here?

This is my code:

```
const calculateExpense = async function (proName) {
        let expensePerProduct = 0;
        fetch('/purchase')
            .then(result => {
                if (result.status >= 400) {
                    throw new Error(result.status);
                } else {
                    return result.json();
                }
            })
            .then(result => {
                let totalExpense = 0;
                let totalQuantity = 0;
                for (let purchase of result) {
                    if (proName == purchase.productName) {
                        totalExpense += purchase.totalPrice;
                        totalQuantity += purchase.purchasedQuantity;
                    }
                }
                expensePerProduct = totalExpense / totalQuantity;
                return expensePerProduct;
            })
            .catch(err => console.log("Error: " + err));
    }
```

I am new to stackoverflow (and to JS), so tell me if you need more information..

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

As you're using `async` (but without the `await`) I would separate out that code into a couple of functions, and use `await` to simplify the handling of the promises.

1) A new `getData` function.

2) A reduced `calculateExpense` function.

```js
async function getData(endpoint) {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(endpoint);
    if (res.status !== 200) throw new Error('Data error');
    return await res.json();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

async function calculateExpense() {
  const data = await getData('/purchase');
  let totalExpense = 0;
  let totalQuantity = 0;
  for (let purchase of data) {
     if (proName == purchase.productName) {
       totalExpense += purchase.totalPrice;
       totalQuantity += purchase.purchasedQuantity;
     }
   }
   return totalExpense / totalQuantity;
}

calculateExpense().then(result => console.log(result));
```

[I've added a working copy (with a mocked fetch function) on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g24f9z67/).

Answer (score 0):

From [async_function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) documentation:

> The async function declaration defines an asynchronous function, which
>   returns an AsyncFunction object. An asynchronous function is a
>   function which operates asynchronously via the event loop, using an
>   implicit Promise to return its result.

This means you need to use `await`, only valid inside async functions, or `then` to get the value with which the promise was resolved.

Also note that you are not returning anything, so the promise is resolved with `undefined` "immediately" (not really true but easier to put it this way), because your function don't contain an `await` expression.

Try something like this:

```
// Using native promises:
const calculateExpense = function (proName) {
    return fetch('/purchase')
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.status >= 400) { throw new Error(response.status.toString()); }

            const result = response.json();

            let totalExpense = 0;
            let totalQuantity = 0;

            for (let purchase of result) {
                if (proName === purchase.productName) {
                    totalExpense += purchase.totalPrice;
                    totalQuantity += purchase.purchasedQuantity;
                }
            }

            return totalExpense / totalQuantity;
        });
};

// Using async/await:
const calculateExpense = async function (proName) {
    const response = await fetch('/purchase');

    if (response.status >= 400) { throw new Error(response.status.toString()); }

    const result = response.json();

    let totalExpense = 0;
    let totalQuantity = 0;

    for (let purchase of result) {
        if (proName === purchase.productName) {
            totalExpense += purchase.totalPrice;
            totalQuantity += purchase.purchasedQuantity;
        }
    }

    return totalExpense / totalQuantity;
};

calculateExpense('name')
    .then((expensePerProduct) => {
        // TODO: do something.
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(`Error: ${err}`));
```